# Where should you install signpost .jars in android studio?

Tags: oauth, android-studio, signpost

I am trying to implement OAuth via signpost in an app and found this tutorial which looks like it is eclipse based.
http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android.html

The relevent instructions:"We will use the excellent signpost Java library to implement OAuth access to Gmail. Just download at least the signpost-core and signpost-commonshttp4 jars, copy them to the lib/ folder inside your Android project, right click on the project, and under Properties/Java Build Path you can add them to the build path:"

I tried moving the mentioned .jars to the app/libs folder in my app with no luck. Am I on the right track or is there a better way to handle OAuth in android studio?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signpost jars are in [Bintray JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/oauth.signpost%3Asignpost-core/view), so you can just add them to your gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    compile(group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-core', version: '1.2.1.2')
    compile(group: 'oauth.signpost', name: 'signpost-commonshttp4', version: '1.2.1.2')
}
```